# unevenly spaced data

Tags: data

Suppose I have a (very large) noisy data set of points $(x_i, y_i)$ and I want to smooth it. Mathematica seems to have a number of smoothing schemes (`EstimatedBackground[]`, `ListConvolve[]`, etc) but they all seem to have the underlying assumption that the data is sampled at regular intervals (and thus, usually takes a flat list of numbers as input), which is not my case (nor, I suspect, is it the case particularly frequently). Is there some more or less standard way to deal with this?

Comment: But you need _some_ assumption about the underlying relation and the noise. Otherwise your perceived "noise" _could_ be your signal.

Comment: @Belisarius Of course. In my case I am doing a computational experiment where I am computing spectral invariants of random (in a certain sense) matrices (so, I have a list of pairs of the form (eigenvalue, some_function_of_eigenvector) of my matrices, which, to make things more annoying, are not precisely the same size. If I do the experiment 1000 times, and compute the mean of my function, and plot it vs the ordinal number of eigenvector, all is well, and the curve is smooth. If I want to plot it against the corresponding eigenvalue, lots of noise. Moving average does sort of work, but...

Comment: ... is not clearly the right thing. In any case, there is the actual  mathematical/scientific problem, and then there is the functionality provided by mathematica, which seems to not be quite what is needed (of course, I can write my own Gauss convolver, or whatever, but this will be actual work and run slowly, too boot :()

Comment: @IgorRivin Can you supply a sample data set or should I experiment on one of my own ?

Comment: @Sektor Sure, watch this space for the Dropbox link.

Comment: @IgorRivin Much better with an example, yes

Comment: @Sektor here you go (warning, large): https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5188175/valnorms.m

Comment: There are generalizations of frequency methods for un-even data eg, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_discrete_Fourier_transform

Comment: @alancalvitti Thanks! That is very cool (though the concerns I expressed before [implementing this is work, and in Mathematica at least will probably be quite slow, when a lot of data is involved] still stand, alas).

Comment: @IgorRivin Thanks Igor ! Already downloaded it and will try a few things on the data :)

Comment: @Sektor thanks! Looking forward to words of wisdom!

Comment: @IgorRivin, at least some special types of generalization of Fourier analysis like chirp-z transforms (off the unit disc) can be made fast like `FFT`.

Comment: @alancalvitti No doubt, but not in Mathematica :( I am perfectly happy to find/prduce implementations (and again, your suggestions are very welcome), but since WRI is making a very big deal of its data handling capabilities, one might hope that there are tools already available. Of course, one might be wrong...

Comment: @alancalvitti And then there is the [devil-z transform](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Devil_Z)

Comment: @belisarius, sooner or later there might be. Maybe fractal in frequency plane like http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DevilsStaircase.html

Answer (score 4):

*Mathematica* 10 has new interesting functions for irregularly spaced data like `MovingMap`

```
data = RandomReal[1, {1000, 2}];

ListLinePlot[MovingMap[Mean, data, {{0.1}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Aha! That could be what I am looking for, I will check it out and report!

Comment: But wait, this is just a generalized `MovingAverage[]`

Comment: @IgorRivin, what functionality were you expecting?

Answer (score 2):

```
Show[
   ListPlot[#,
    DataRange -> {0, 6 Pi},
    PlotTheme -> "Detailed",
    PlotStyle -> PointSize[Tiny]],

   ListLinePlot[
    MovingMap[Mean, #, {{250}, Center}, 0],
    PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue},
    DataRange -> {0, 6 Pi}]] & [Table[Cos[x] + RandomReal[{-1, 1}], {x, 0, 6 Pi, 0.01}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I will try with my data, and report.

Comment: On second thought, your data _is_ actually regularly spaced (and so, just like the built-in stuff, you are not using the abscissas...)